# Basic posting of data from frontend to backend

Tags: reactjs, forms, post, axios, jsx

I'm making my first steps with React and got stuck on POST-ing data from a simple user registration form to the backend API. For some reason, when I press the "Register" button in the form and want to call `handleSubmit`, it doesn't get called and instead throws some error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import NavBar from '../NavBar';

class RegistrationForm extends Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            display: '',
            email: '',
            pswd: ''
        }

        console.log("RegistrationForm constructor");
    };

    changeNameValue = (e) =>    { this.setState({ name: e }) }
    changeDisplayValue = (e) => { this.setState({ display: e }) }
    changeEmailValue = (e) =>   { this.setState({ email: e }) }
    changePswdValue = (e) =>    { this.setState({ pswd: e }) }

    handleSubmit = () => {
        console.log("handleSubmit()");

        const data = {
            username: this.state.name,
            displayname: this.state.display,
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.pswd
        }
        axios.post(
            'http://localhost:9000/api/registeruser',
            { body: JSON.stringify(data) }
        ).then(res => console.log("Posted"));
    }

    render() {
        var logoImage = require('../../images/logo_v3_150.png');

        return (
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100vh' }}>
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        <img src={logoImage} width='150' height='184' /><br />
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <form>
                            <input value={this.state.name} onChange={(e) =>     this.changeNameValue(e.target.value)} placeholder='Username' /><br />
                            <input value={this.state.display} onChange={(e) =>  this.changeDisplayValue(e.target.value)} placeholder='Display Name' /><br />
                            <input value={this.state.email} onChange={(e) =>    this.changeEmailValue(e.target.value)} placeholder='Email' /><br />
                            <input value={this.state.pswd} onChange={(e) =>     this.changePswdValue(e.target.value)} placeholder='Password' /><br />
                            <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Register</button>
                        </form>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <NavBar />
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default RegistrationForm;
```

The error (only this message in the Firefox's Dev Tools):
[image]
[image]

This is probably something silly that I missed but I can't figure it out by myself.

Comment: Could you post the error ?

Comment: Added a screenshot to the post.

Comment: Are you sure `handleSubmit` is never called? `createError.js` from you screenshot is a function in the axios package, so it looks like the request has been fired, but with an error. Check the network tab for errors in your request? Clicking Console in the developer tools might show you something

Comment: My console.log() call is before the axios.post() call and I don't see my message in the console, hence I assumed handleSubmit() is not called.

Comment: Could you post the error you get in your console tab instead of the Debugger

Comment: I added a screenshot of the Console tab.

Comment: So this is actually an error in your post request, not sure why your console.log isn't firing

Comment: I'm calling the GET method at the same route (`'http://localhost:9000/api/registeruser'`) and I see the backend is responding to that. Just the POST doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Check the network tab once to see if the request is actually made from client.

Comment: I see all the requests are only sent to 127.0.0.1:3000 which is where my frontend is running (backend is on port 9000).